# creating arbitrary page layouts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to add a theme or plugin to my wordpress install such that I can quickly build pages with arbitrary layouts, mixing bars of 2, 3, and 4 columns, containing widgets, HTML, etc.

I've been looking at carrington build but it doesn't let me reuse bars across different pages, and it seems to be limited in the bar layouts (no 4 column bar for example).

i've also looked at plugins like widgets on pages but in that case I have to do a lot of CSS hacking to create a 4 column bar, for example.

is there a recommended plugin or theme or way to solve this problem? i'm not a design guru, i'm looking for a simple solution that just works. I love the unbounce.com editor of pages, why isn't there something like that for wordpress???

Answer (score 0):

You can make different template files for different pages/categories/etc. There is more than one way to get there, the easiest is with naming.

If you like to have a page with different layouts, just create a `page-<my-pagename>.php` and copy the content of `page.php` in it.

Now to make your own markup. Go to the Wordpress backend and edit your page. At the right-hand side, select the template you wish to use for this page, select `page-<my-pagename>`. Other ways are described [here](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/custom-wordpress-page-templates/).

Comment: thanks, but i am really looking for a visual editor of some sort and the ones out there like pagelines are too limited.